# codeigniter redirect when not login

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a login process in codeigniter because I'm new to it and want to familiarize myself with it. Then I want to add a security feature where if the dashboard is accessed using the URL, if the session of `account_id` is not set I will redirect them to login:

```
 public function index() {

    if ($this->session->userdata('account_id') === FALSE ) {


      redirect('/');
    }    

    return $this->_renderPage();
}
```

but then it gives me this result
[image]

As you can see it's still in the dashboard but its all blank page and it did not redirect.
How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you load the right helper ? Do it with `$this->load->helper('url');`.

After you can use redirect like this: `redirect('/', 'refresh');`

[The CodeIgniter documentation about url helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

---

*PS*: The PHP way to do this is `header('Location: http://www.website.com/');`